# Is there way to print 1:1 image on Canon Selphy CP820?

Tags: canon, printing, scale

I have Canon Selphy CP820 (model not matter actually) and want to print image without any scaling and cropping.
Original paper is proprietary 148x100mm. It prints at 300dpi. But when I trying to print 1618x1854 image in borderless mode - It scale it up and cut. E.g. 64x44mm object will be 68x47mm on paper.

How can I print as is? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a printer, a computer and or software involved in this process?

Comment: @AlaskaMan, actually I tried printing directly from USB flash drive connected to printer and from Computer with Linux (CUPS+Guttenprint driver) and got the same results.

Comment: Printing smaller image than papper could be a hack but how to find maximal resolution, which will not to be changed by printer firmware